# Erro ao escrever arquivo no Android

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando criar um arquivo no Android, mas está aparecendo uma letra que eu não quero que seja gravada. Observe o código:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "Arquivo.sth");
try { file.createNewFile(); }
catch (Exception e) { file = null; }
if (file != null) {
    try {
        char[] chars = new char[8];
        chars[0] = (char)84;
        chars[1] = (char)66;
        chars[2] = (char)76;
        chars[3] = (char)33;
        chars[4] = (char)107;
        chars[5] = (char)0;
        chars[6] = (char)5;
        chars[7] = (char)153;

        Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        w.write(chars, 0, chars.length);
        w.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

O código consegue escrever todos os caracteres. Porém, o arquivo devia ter 8 bytes, mas tem 9. Um byte surge não sei de onde e ele aparece no arquivo antes do último caractere.

Será que é porque eu estou usando UTF-8? Qual charset eu devia usar nesse caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O "*problema*" está na representação do decimal pela tabela escolhida, ele é conhecido como [DBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBCS) atribuído normalmente ao UTF-8 e UTF-16;

```
chars[7] = (char)153;
```

O *decimal-153* faz parte da [tabela extendida ASCII (128-255)](http://www.ascii-code.com) nesse caso o simbolo de representação irá diferir conforme a tabela de Charset definida para representação:

Usando ISO 8859-1 (aka ISO Latin-1), será gerado um um arquivo de 8 bytes, no UTF-8 muitas dessas representações utilizam 2 bytes, o que é o caso do decimal 153 no UTF-8.

**ISO 8859-1**

> ™

**UTF-8**

> Ù

Portanto, uma das soluções seria:

```
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado. Agora os bytes estão sendo gravados corretamente, mas quando eu abro no bloco de notas do Windows os caracteres aparecem em japonês ou chinês, tem como corrigir isso?

Comment: @JhonasBoeno tem sim, vou consolidar melhor minha resposta explicando a melhor prática que é usando UNICODE, só preciso de um tempo livre pra isso, hoje a noite eu faço.